# How to horizontally center a header that is position:absolute

Tags: html, css, image, header, positioning

I'm trying to horizontally and vertically center a header on top of an image. So far I've got the vertical centering down (which is the reason for the relative and absolute positioning). However, the horizontal centering is giving me problems now: `margin:0 auto;` doesn't work, `left:50%;` doesn't work and `text-align:center` doesn't work. Does anyone know how to horizontally center the header on top of the image?

*Details:*

- *I don't know the height or width of any of the elements, so I can't use fixed heights or widths*
- *Setting the image as a background is not an option because the image is part of the content*
- *Not all headers will be a similar length, so I have to find a dynamic solution (they will all be one line though, I'll cut them off with an ellipsis)*

HTML

```
<article>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <img src="http://bit.ly/gUKbAE" />
</article>
```

CSS

```
article { 
    position: relative; 
}

h2 {
    line-height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; 
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

It's here: http://jsfiddle.net/kmjRu/21/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `article` to `display: inline-block` and `width: auto`, then center the `h2`:
http://jsfiddle.net/kmjRu/28/

Comment: Wow, that's great! Could it also be done with the h2 on top in the html? Because I see it disappears if I change the order. Why is that?

Comment: I see that z-index fixes that, I don't understand why, but at least I can fix it :)

Comment: It's just because of the positioning. It can be done: just set the `h2`'s `z-index` to something higher, like `1`.

Comment: I forgot one thing: I have a div that crops the image when it exceeds the screen width and now the solution doesn't work. I've put it here: http://jsfiddle.net/kmjRu/30/. Do you have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: @Samuel Wrong JSFiddle? The image doesn't 'crop', it just scrolls off the screen...

Comment: Yeah it doesn't work. This is what it's meant to do: http://jsfiddle.net/kmjRu/31/. But I guess it doesn't because the elements are out of the documents flow. Do you know how to restore that and base the horizontal centering on the visible portion of the image? Or should I ask a new question because this is to different from the original question?

Comment: @Samuel So you want the text to be centered on the window when the image is cropped?

Comment: Yeah, and I'm trying to hide any overflow that is more than 100% window width.

Comment: This should do: http://jsfiddle.net/kmjRu/32/ (SO is warning us not to post any more comments :P)

Comment: Just one more: thank you very much, it works perfectly. You're obviously a lot better at this than I am. Thank you!